# Can I re-install OS X on an encrypted drive without the password?

Tags: macos, password, install

I don't know my password to my Mac OS X account and it has file encrypt enabled on drive. If I reinstall Mac OS X, will it require a password to do so?

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need your FileVault password to erase and re-install OS X.

Without your password you will not be able to recover the existing files, but you will be able to completely blank and reinstall OS X on the Mac.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Once I've reinstalled it, will it have some sort of iCloud lock or way of locking me out of doing anything once I'm logged in. Reason I ask is because I'm buying it from a pawn shop.?

Comment: If the Mac has been erased and re-installed, I do not believe it will but I am not certain. You may want to [ask a new question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about this – or maybe this question will help http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80490/does-find-my-mac-stop-working-after-the-system-has-been-wiped