# Will erasing a Macbook Pro via the FindMyiPhone site erase Windows partitions?

Tags: mac, bootcamp, find-my-iphone, find-my-mac

My mac was stolen, I requested that the mac be erased on this portal: [Find My iPhone](https://www.icloud.com/#find).

I used Windows 10 via Bootcamp. Will this partition be erased as well? The 'erasing' was triggered last night so someone definitely used the computer to access the internet. It's quite important to know if the Windows partition will be erased or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Find My Mac stop working after the system has been wiped?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80490/does-find-my-mac-stop-working-after-the-system-has-been-wiped)