# Does Find My Mac work if the disk gets erased?

Tags: macbook-pro, find-my-mac

My MacBook Pro was stolen a couple of days ago and Find my Mac had been enabled on it. I have already locked the Mac with a passcode and a message as well as clicked on the play sound feature(on the find my iPhone app), but those actions are pending until the computer comes online. The Mac is on El Capitan and came with Mavericks. The admin user is password protected but I had not enabled FileVault which is the disk encryption feature, so the computer can be wiped by erasing the disk in Recovery. The computer doesn't need to connect to the internet to be erased but it does need an internet connection to reinstall the operating system after the wipe. My question is, if the computer is erased and then goes online, will Find my Mac still work and notify me when it does? Is it still asociated with my Apple ID after the wipe?

Comment: its part of iCloud - if your mac is erased, then the required iCloud info go to, phone Apple and tell them its been stolen, they will help.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the thief does not manually clear the NVRAM in any way, or reconfigures iCloud with another account, the device can still be tracked when online.

see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/64606/203415)