# Find My [Mac] reported location without WiFi?

Tags: wifi, security, find-my-mac

I was the owner of a Macbook Pro w/ Touchbar running macOS Mojave last week-end

The macbook has been stolen and moved 300 miles away from the point. I got two alerts separated by a few hours, around the same area. The pending lock hasn't been triggered unfortunately. But the "Sound" has been triggered.

The question is how did it send the location to Apple without Wifi? (it is not online, but just got located once or twice)

Did the thief crack my credentials and then logged in some Wifi?

Or did my macbook connect to a Wifi with the same SSID than a hotspot ?

Could the thief connect to the Wifi without being logged in?

Can the Macbook connect to any Wifi when in recovery/reset mode and trigger an alert on the Macbook?

Comment: I'm sorry for your loss. Why do you assume the Mac must have connected using Wifi? Apple says location data is created "...when the Mac _is online."_  "Online" doesn't mean only Wifi, and doesn't mean continually, but Apple doesn't say exactly how. The Mac might have been briefly connected via wifi, then disconnected. The Mac might have been online using Ethernet, using an Ethernet cable through a dongle plugged in to the Mac's USB-C port. I suppose it might even have been connected via Bluetooth.

Comment: It looks like the bluetooth mesh network is only part of Catalina (I should have upgraded it...)
cf. https://www.theverge.com/2019/6/3/18647146/apple-find-my-app-tracker-friends-iphone-wwdc-2019 or 
https://www.wired.com/story/apple-find-my-cryptography-bluetooth/

Hopefully it is when it was recovered or reseted (kept the FindMy token in NVRAM as described https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64204/why-does-a-macbook-pro-keep-dialing-in-its-location-through-find-my-mac-after-a ) or ethernet.

I am afraid for my data

Comment: If your data is backed up, you should delete the data on the Mac.

Comment: Yes I asked for erasing... pending.